# Assign DataGridRow.Header Value from DataRow Nth column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataTable Dt` as a `ItemsSource` for my DataGrid and I was wondering if there is any way to bind a cell value from Nth column to each `DataGridRow.Header`?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dt}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
            <!-- how to bind value from Dt Nth column?-->
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding} "/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Currently my output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Value[0]?

Comment: did you mean `<Setter Property="Header" Value="0" />` ? Sorry, im out of office and cannot check it now in the code....

Comment: still somehow, cannot get it right working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this where N = 1:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding [1]}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, it works! One more thing I was wondering - I am trying to assign index to static value, but no success so far. What am I missing?  `<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding [{x:Static local:Globals.Value}]}"/>`